# ModelState.IsValid is validating referenced entity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I have the following entity:

```
public class Ambiente
{
    public int AmbienteId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Codigo del Ambiente")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage ="El ancho máximo es de 10 caracteres")]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Nombre del Ambiente")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage ="El ancho máximo es de 50 caracteres")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Especifique una etapa")]
    [Display(Name ="Nombre de la Etapa")]
    public Etapa Etapa { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see, this class has a property which references an entity called Etapa

```
public class Etapa
{
    public int EtapaId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Especifique un nombre de Etapa")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El ancho maximo es de 20")]
    [Display(Name ="Nombre de la Etapa")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

This class Etapa has a validation over the property Nombre. Now regarding the  class Ambiente, when submitting data in order to insert in the database I use this code in my Insertar Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insertar(Ambiente ambiente)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _ambienteRepository.Insertar(ambiente);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    var ambienteViewModel = ObtenerAmbienteViewModel(ambiente);
    return View(ambienteViewModel);
}
```

when this code reaches the ModelState.IsValid sentence it throws false and the following message appears:

> "Especifique un nombre de Etapa"

Which is the text of the property Nombre of my Etapa class.

[image]

When I quickwatch my variable ambiente from the parameter in my Insertar Action I see the following:

[image]

This Etapa entity is used to populate a dropdown list in my view. All the values already exist in the database, so it's not my intention to add records to this entity.

[image]

I don't know how to bypass the validation of this referenced entity Etapa.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to create a viewmodel , don't include `Etapa` property . Assign values to `Ambiente` object on server side before inserting to database.

If you don't want to change anything . Based on your code ,you can ignore the model state error for Etapa by(but is not a good idea) :

```
ModelState.Remove("Etapa");
```

Then assign the required `Etapa` to make sure `Nombre`is not empty .The code will like :

```
ModelState.Remove("Etapa");
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var etapa = _context.Etapa.First(a => a.EtapaId == ambiente.Etapa.EtapaId);
    ambiente.Etapa = etapa;
    _context.Add(ambiente);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    .....
}
```

Comment: Bad practice indeed, but it worked like a charm in my particular case. Thank you!